# Spark number minus the same number in preview time

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, aggregate-functions

The source is a csv file:

```
id,sale,date
1,100,201901
1,105,201902
1,107,201904
1,108,201905
2,10,201901
2,11,201902
2,12,201904
2,13,201905
```

It is about some sales of products,  `1,100,201901` means from the  beginning till the date 201901,100 products which id is 1 had been sold.

`1,105,201902` means from the  beginning till the date 201902,105 products which id is 1 had been sold.So in the second month of year 2019,only 5 product 1 s were sold out.

What I expect is add a column to it using apache spark which denotes how many product were sold in the current month.

The expected result is:

```
id,sale,date,inc
1,100,201901,0
1,105,201902,5
1,107,201904,2
1,108,201905,1
2,10,201901,1
2,11,201902,1
2,12,201904,1
2,13,201905,1
```

In the real case,it is batch jobs.

I have tired to use join (code below), I am not sure if I should use rollup or cube or accumulator.

If we execute a batch job each month,it seems OK,the problem is if some month we forget to run the batch job,we will run it in the next month.

For example, the last line of code will show:

```
| id|sale|  date|saleInc|
+---+----+------+-------+
|  1|2000|201901|   null|
|  1|2005|201902|      5|
|  1|2007|201903|      7|
+---+----+------+-------+
```

but actually,201903 the saleInc should be 2 not 7,it should be `2007 - 2005` but not `2007-2000`

It is just my code, you could not depend on it,you can use another way.

```
package incremental.test
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
//import com.qydata.stock.db._//a02z10 av1049 1yue29
import scala.reflect.api.materializeTypeTag
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.SHUFFLE_PARTITIONS
import scala.xml.dtd.Scanner
object D20190123 {
     def main(args: Array[String]){
       
       var sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]")//.set("spark.default.parallelism","1").set("spark.streaming.blockInterval", "1").set("spark.shuffle.sort.bypassMergeThreshold", "1").set("spark.executor.cores", "1") .set("spark.executor.cores", "1")
           // .set("spark.cores.max", "1")
       val builder =  SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf)//.enableHiveSupport()  
       val ss =  builder.getOrCreate()  
       import ss.implicits._
       ss.sessionState.conf.setConf(SHUFFLE_PARTITIONS, 1)
       var sc = ss.sparkContext
       sc.setLogLevel("error");


      
      var hive=Seq.empty[( Int,Int,String,Int)].toDF("id","sale","date","saleInc")
      println("====hive"); hive.show()
      
       val mongo1=Seq((1,2000,"201901")).toDF("id","sale","date");
       println("====mongo1"); mongo1.show()
       val newOfMongo1= mongo1.where('date>197001)
       println("====newOfMongo1"); newOfMongo1.show()
       val saleInHive1=hive.groupBy("id").agg('id,max('sale) as "mx").select($"id" as "hid",'mx)
       println("====saleInHive1");saleInHive1.show()
       val hiveAppend1=newOfMongo1.join(saleInHive1,'id==='hid,"left").withColumn("saleInc", 'sale-'mx)
       .select("id","sale","date","saleInc")
       println("====hiveAppend1");hiveAppend1.show()
       hive=hive.union(hiveAppend1)
       println("====hive"); hive.show()
       
      /* second batch may be missed
       * 
//       var hive=mongo1.select('id, 'sale,lit(0) as 'saleInc)//Seq((1,2000,0)).toDF("id","sale","saleInc")
       val mongo2=Seq((1,2000,"201901"),(1,2005,"201902")).toDF("id","sale","date")
       println("====mongo2"); mongo2.show()
       val newOfMongo2= mongo2.where('date>201901)
       println("====newOfMongo2"); newOfMongo2.show()
       val saleInHive2=hive.groupBy("id").agg('id,max('sale) as "mx").select($"id" as "hid",'mx)
       println("====saleInHive2");saleInHive2.show()
       val hiveAppend2=newOfMongo2.join(saleInHive2,'id==='hid,"left").withColumn("saleInc", 'sale-'mx)
       .select("id","sale","date","saleInc")
       println("====hiveAppend2");hiveAppend2.show()
       hive=hive.union(hiveAppend2)
       println("====hive"); hive.show()
       */
       
       val mongo3=Seq((1,2000,"201901"),(1,2005,"201902"),(1,2007,"201903")).toDF("id","sale","date")
       println("====mongo3"); mongo3.show()
       val newOfMongo3= mongo3.where('date>201901)//02
       println("====newOfMongo3"); newOfMongo3.show()
       val saleInHive3=hive.groupBy("id").agg('id,max('sale) as "mx").select($"id" as "hid",'mx)
       println("====saleInHive3"); saleInHive3.show()
       val hiveAppend3=newOfMongo3.join(saleInHive3,'id==='hid,"left").withColumn("saleInc", 'sale-'mx)
       .select("id","sale","date","saleInc")
       println("====hiveAppend3");hiveAppend3.show()
       hive=hive.union(hiveAppend3)
       
       println("====hive");hive.show()

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a `lag`

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df.withColumn( 
  "inc",
   $"sale" - lag($"sale", 1).over(Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"date")))
```

Comment: Great! It can be so simple